# how thread code

Tags: swift

I got a small problem, let me start with the code

```
  @IBAction func viewPlaceAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("00")
    getParsePlaceView()


     // json viewPlace
    print("06")
        // do some task
          performSegueWithIdentifier("viewPlaceSegu", sender: sender)


}



   @IBAction func tourAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
    /// Open the page
        // parse json
    func getParsePlaceView(){
         let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        print("01")

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){ [unowned self] (data , repsonse , error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {

                    print("02")
                do {
                    let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                    for post in posts {

                        if let id = post["userId"] as? Int{

                         // print(id)

                            let sets = Country(id: id)
                            self.CountrySelected.append(sets)

                        }



                    }
                    self.countryArry = posts
                    print("03")
                 //   print(self.countryArry)

                    print("04")
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()
  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
            print("05")
            print(self.countryArry)
        }
}


}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    if segue.identifier == "viewPlaceSegu" {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewPlace {

            // set a variable in the second view controller with the String to pass
            print("07")
            secondViewController.tnt = countryArry
            print("08")

        }

    }
}
```

I want to be as follows but output

This codes give me a output in the console of

> "01" "01" "07" "08" "0" "(" ")" "0" "0" "05" "(" ")" "02" "03" "04"

how can I get to the output.

"00" "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08"

Comment: This might be an asynchronous issue. The last line is executed before what's inside NSURLSession, because it takes some time so send an receive server's response. NSURLSession are handled asynchronously

Comment: just didn't understand you. What do you think . ؟

Comment: Do you know what asynchronous request is ? To see it: just after line //1, write 'print("1")'. Just after line //2, write 'print("2")'. When you execute the code, you should see:
2,
then
nil,
then
1

Comment: Yes. You are right .but I have to do what ؟؟

Comment: Well... This is how HTTP calls work, it is meant to be asynchronous, so I suggest you keep it asynchronous. You should just call the next instructions on countryArr from inside the method, just after  'self.countryArry = posts', not in the last line of your code.

Comment: I don't think that's true .I 'll pass 'countryArry'  to the tableview ,and I need to have it out

Comment: if your issue is to update a tableview once the country array is loaded, you can refresh it with self.tableView.reloadData() in the tableviewcellcontroller

Comment: can cheak my code in [link](http://pastebin.com/mgxg9zqe )
tank you .

Comment: the problem is still: the call is async and it works on the non ui thread. you have to adress both problems. so is your question on the async. behavior or on when and how to update the ui?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich update code . but the problem is still :(

Comment: Pass the url to the destinationviewcontroller. Or performsegue when you have fetched the data at about 03 or 04 ( and not directly when scheduling the task to fetch)

Comment: I really appreciate your help . it's right @ChristianDietrich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dataTaskWithURL spawns an async task. the completion handler closure you define will be executing when response from the server comes. thus countryArry will not (yet) be set. so the actuall flow is

- tell NSURLSession to do its work
- go on with `print(countryArry)`
- NSURLSession will do its work and call back the block

Or to take a real world analogy

- call someone and ask him to do a task (he will call you back when he is done. you will write down his answer on paper)
- look at the paper

of course the paper is empty since you did so receive him calling back

Comment: just didn't understand you